# Why did the development of major Mathematics in America only start after 1900s?

Tags: mathematics, education

America was found in 1492, yet the big names of American mathematics only come up later than 1900s. I also get a feeling that as years went on since 1900, the focus was more on abstract mathematics, peaking at 1950s with findings of ideas such as Category theory and so on. Why did the development stay stagnant till this time?

Comment: No America tag so :c

Comment: America was found (as in discovered) much earlier.

Comment: There is a book called "A History Of Mathematics In America Before 1900" by Smith and Ginsburg. And "The Bicentennial Tribute to American Mathematics (1776-1976)": Editor Dalton Tarwater. O. F. Mossotti's 19th century period teaching mathematics and physics in Argentina (in political exile from Italy) seems more significant for the Americas though less studied in the English speaking world.

Comment: Mathematics in America did not peak in the 1950s in any sense.

Comment: There is a 3-volume collection published by the AMS called "A Century of Mathematics in America" and I think volumes 2 and 3 would interest you.

Answer (score 6):

It is absolutely irrelevant for the question when America was discovered. The first university on the US territory was founded in 1636. But until 20th century most universities taught mostly elementary mathematics. In general, mathematical research was a very localized phenomenon until 20th century, mainly cultivated in Germany, France, Britain and Italy. Contribution of other countries was relatively small, and in most other countries it did not exist at all.

In the end of 19th century American students started to travel to Germany to study advanced mathematics, and then returned home to teach it on American soil. Later two events
helped to move America to the top in mathematics: first, large immigration in the 1930s of mathematicians who escaped the Nazi regime and the war, and second, the arms race and
space race after WWII. It was understood that mathematics is important and money was pumped into math education and research
during this period, since American public understood that mathematics is important for defense and competition in technologies.

In most other countries, mathematical research
(I mean "modern mathematics") started much later, in the second half of 20th century. This includes countries like China, India or Turkey which were "discovered" much earlier that America.

Remark. Since you mention category theory which arose as a part of topology, let me cite Richard Courant on American mathematics of 1930s:

> ``I think that when the Americans first became research-conscious they
> took up the newer fields which didn't require so much background;
> for example, they went into abstract algebra and topology.
> In the early 1900's those were new fields. One could understand what had
> been done without too much background.
> One could see any number of problems that were open.
> If they had chosen to go into analysis, they would have had to acquire much
> more extensive backgrounds before they could do original work of their own.
> I think that people in our country got started the easiest way at the time.''

Comment: Thanks for the great quote!